# Average case complexity - calculation for linear algorithm

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

Just a quick question:

If I have a linear search algorithm (which will go through every element once up to a certain condition), how can I calculate the average case complexity for n = 500? The worst case and best case is easy.

Comment: If it's counting linearly, wouldn't it just be 250?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The average case is similarly simple: as long as the items you're finding are unique, on average you will have to look halfway through the list + 0.5.

Let's assume that you look up every item in the list once.  When you look up the first item, you will have to inspect 1 item.  When you look up the second item, you will have to inspect 2 items, and so forth.  The total number of inspections is

```
1 + 2 + 3 + ... + 500 = 125250
```

So with 500 lookups, you will total 125250 items inspected.  On average, that is 250.5 inspections per lookup.

If your lookup patterns are nonuniform then that will skew your average case (for example, if you look up items at the beginning of the list more often, or if some items are repeated and finding any of them is sufficient)

Comment: Yeah, that's kind of what I thought, but I remember for some reason my teacher said that was not correct during a lecture. However, it makes perfect sense to me. Thanks!

Comment: The thing that surprised me when I was actually calculating the complexity is that the answer is 250.5 instead of 250.

Comment: If it surprises you just remember the formula for the sum of basic arithmetic series (1+2+...+n). It's (number of terms)*(first term + last term)/2. Since you are dividing that sum by the number of terms, what you calculate is just (first term + last term) / 2. In this case (500 + 1) / 2

Answer (score 0):

The average case complexity of a linear search algorithm is n+2
where n is the number of elements in the list.